# Why str can't get a second parameter,when __str__ can?

Tags: python, string, methods, tree, operator-overloading

I decided to use str for printing the contents of a tree in tree-like structure,using something like

```
print tree
```

The nodes of the tree are all objects of user-created classes and I overload their `__str__` magic method in order to use the child nodes' str after indent t tabs like that

```
def __str__ (self,t=0) :`
    return t*'\t' + str(self.label) +':' +'\n'+ str(self.l,t+1)+'\n'+str(self.right,t+1)+'\n'
```

However I can't call `str` with that `t` parameter,but I can call `node.__ str__(t=4)`.Isn't `str`,only shortcut to the magic method?Or is that because the parser rejects additional params to `str` without checking the magic method?

P.S. I am interested in the behaviour.I know that's not the best way to print a tree,it was a hack ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Imagine it this way.

```
def str(obj):
    try:
        return obj.__str__()
    except ...:
        ...
```

Just because `__str__` can take more parameters, doesn't mean that `str` is configured to pass those parameters through.

Comment: but if str behaves as in your example,it'll work if obj.__str__() doesn't lead to exception.And it doesn't in my case.

Comment: @Alexander Ivanov: The `...` in the code is *omitted code*, just for illustration purposes only.  I did not intend to give a complete implementation of `str`.

Comment: i know,I got confused by something else

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Class `C` with a method `__str__(self, t=0)`, `str(c)` will call `C.__str__(c)` which sets t to zero as declared. `str()` itself only accepts one argument.